# Reactjs: where is the file path for a file uploaded in the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, 7zip

I'm using reactjs and chrome.

I have built a webpage where I can upload an archive file and I want to do some further work on the file.

When the archive file is 7zip, I am using this library [node-7z](https://npm.io/package/node-7z) to try to extract a single file from the it.

The official documentation in the link suggests to use it like this:

```
// myStream is a Readable stream
const myStream = Seven.extractFull('./archive.7z', './output/dir/', {
  $progress: true
})
```

My code (part of it):

```
import sevenBin from '7zip-bin'
import Seven from 'node-7z'


const _7zOpen = async (f) => {
  console.log('_7zOpen !! ', f)
  
  // myStream is a Readable stream
  const myStream = Seven.extractFull(f.path, './output/dir/', {
    $progress: true
  })

  myStream.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data)
  })

  myStream.on('progress', function (progress) {
    console.log(progress)
  })

}
```

where the input `f` is a file object:

```
_7zOpen !!  
File {path: 'CE027001-120011101924-T100.7z', 
name: 'CE027001-120011101924-T100.7z', 
lastModified: 1599377977254, 
lastModifiedDate: Sun Sep 06 2020 16:39:37 GMT+0900, webkitRelativePath: '', …}
lastModified: 1599377977254
lastModifiedDate: Sun Sep 06 2020 16:39:37 GMT+0900 {}
name: "CE027001-120011101924-T100.7z"
path: "CE027001-120011101924-T100.7z"
size: 75602083
type: "application/x-7z-compressed"
webkitRelativePath: ""
[[Prototype]]: File
```

It gives an error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): spawn is not a function
▼ 3 stack frames were expanded.
run
node_modules/node-7z/src/lifecycle.js:74
(anonymous function)
node_modules/node-7z/src/main.js:55
extractFull
node_modules/node-7z/src/commands.js:27
▲ 3 stack frames were expanded.

_7zOpen
src/components/shared/utils/compressedFileHandler.js:56
  53 | 
  54 | 
  55 | const pathTo7zip = sevenBin.path7za;
> 56 | const seven = Seven.extractFull(f.path, './output/dir/', {
     | ^  57 |   $bin: pathTo7zip
  58 | });
  59 |
```

---

I tried another way:

```
const _7zOpen = async (f) => {
  console.log('_7zOpen !! ', f)
  
  const pathTo7zip = sevenBin.path7za;
  const seven = Seven.extractFull(f.path, './output/dir/', {
    $bin: pathTo7zip
  });

}
```

which gives the same error message when the file is uploaded.

It could be that the `f.path` is not valid.
How can I find the correct path to feed to the function?

Comment: That's not the full error.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have added some more error messages. These are as much as the browser gives

Comment: Please only show the code that the error belongs to, or show the error that belongs to the code you show. Right now, the error seems for "not the code you're showing".

Comment: I think that you are mixing two different environments: browser and server. That lib is supposed for node.js (server side) where you have access to filesystem. Javascript on webpage can't access user's filesystem. That's it.